# Swift Array extension with where clause doesn't work on sub-protocols

Tags: swift, swift-extensions, swift-protocols

I've written some code that I think *ought* to work in Swift 2 (Xcode 7b4), but it's not compiling.  I'm hoping to get some thoughts on whether what I'm trying to do should be valid.

Consider this example `Array` extension:

```
extension Array where Element: AnyObject {
    mutating func appendUniqueInstance(e: Element) {
        for element in self {
            if (element === e) {
                return
            }
        }

        self.append(e)
    }
}
```

First, what do I mean by an Array whose elements are `AnyObject`?  Basically I'm saying the array should contain a heterogeneous group of non-value-type objects that can be compared for instance equality (`===`).

The example function `appendUniqueInstance()` only inserts an element into an array if it isn't already in the array.  This is similar to a `Set` `insert()` operation but obviously provides ordering and (more importantly) does not impose `Set`'s homogeneous-type requirement (via `Equatable`'s use of `Self`).

If I now define a protocol `P` and a class `C` that implements `P`:

```
protocol P : AnyObject {}

class C : P {}
```

and instantiate a `C`:

`let c = C()`

Then these very obvious things are true:

```
let cIsAnyObject = c as AnyObject   // ok
let cIsP = c as P                   // ok
```

And I can now do the following:

```
var a1 = [AnyObject]()              // []

a1.appendUniqueInstance(c)          // [c]
a1.appendUniqueInstance(c)          // [c]
```

So far, so good, but now for the problem case:

```
var a2 = [P]()

a2.append(c)                        // ok, -> [c]

// Compiler error: Cannot invoke 'appendUniqueInstance' with an argument list of type '(C)'
a2.appendUniqueInstance(c)
```

Here, `a2` is typed as an array of `P`, so it should be a perfectly valid thing to do to `append` an instance of `P`, and indeed the line `a2.append(c)` works as we'd expect.

Calling the `Array` extension function `appendUniqueInstance()` however generates a compiler error.

As far as I can tell, the compiler seems to be getting confused about what can be passed to `appendUniqueInstance()` and not realizing (or allowing for some reason) that `C` (via `P`) is an `AnyObject`.

Incidentally, if I declare `P` instead as:

`@objc protocol P : AnyObject {}`

then everything compiles just fine, but I also then have to make sure everything in protocol `P` conforms to `@objc`, which is not what I want.

So, after all of this, my question is: does this seem like something that should work?  I hope it isn't just a case of getting some declaration syntax wrong, but I guess I'll be glad if it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the error reported by the compiler at the time I wrote the original question was simply misleading, and the functionality I was trying to obtain wasn't (and still isn't) supported by Swift.

With Xcode 8.2.1 and Swift 3 a more accurate error is reported:

```
// error: using 'P' as a concrete type conforming
//   to protocol 'AnyObject' is not supported
a2.appendUniqueInstance(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you command click on `AnyObject`  you will notice that it is an protocol that conforms to @objc. So I am guessing that is the reason why it asks to use @objc. I noticed that if we make C a subclass of NSObject you do not need to explicitly make the implementation of methods from `P` to conform to @objc

```
@objc protocol P : AnyObject {
    func hey()
}

class C : NSObject, P {
    func hey() {
        print("hey")
    }
}
```